# What is the significance of the numbers in the name of the flush processes for newer linux kernels?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am running kernel 2.6.33.7.

Previously, I was running v2.6.18.x. On 2.6.18, the flush processes were named pdflush.

After upgrading to 2.6.33.7, the flush processes have a format of "flush-:".
For example, currently I see flush process "flush-8:32" popping up in top.

In doing a google search to try to determine an answer to this question, I saw examples of "flush-8:38", "flush-8:64" and "flush-253:0" just to name a few.

I understand what the flush process itself does, my question is what is the significance of the numbers on the end of the process name? What do they represent?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Device numbers used to identify block devices.  A kernel thread may be spawned to handle a particular device.

(On one of my systems, block devices are currently numbered as shown below.  They may change from boot to boot or hotplug to hotplug.)

```
$ grep ^ /sys/class/block/*/dev
/sys/class/block/dm-0/dev:254:0
/sys/class/block/dm-1/dev:254:1
/sys/class/block/dm-2/dev:254:2
/sys/class/block/dm-3/dev:254:3
/sys/class/block/dm-4/dev:254:4
/sys/class/block/dm-5/dev:254:5
/sys/class/block/dm-6/dev:254:6
/sys/class/block/dm-7/dev:254:7
/sys/class/block/dm-8/dev:254:8
/sys/class/block/dm-9/dev:254:9
/sys/class/block/loop0/dev:7:0
/sys/class/block/loop1/dev:7:1
/sys/class/block/loop2/dev:7:2
/sys/class/block/loop3/dev:7:3
/sys/class/block/loop4/dev:7:4
/sys/class/block/loop5/dev:7:5
/sys/class/block/loop6/dev:7:6
/sys/class/block/loop7/dev:7:7
/sys/class/block/md0/dev:9:0
/sys/class/block/md1/dev:9:1
/sys/class/block/sda/dev:8:0
/sys/class/block/sda1/dev:8:1
/sys/class/block/sda2/dev:8:2
/sys/class/block/sdb/dev:8:16
/sys/class/block/sdb1/dev:8:17
/sys/class/block/sdb2/dev:8:18
/sys/class/block/sdc/dev:8:32
/sys/class/block/sdc1/dev:8:33
/sys/class/block/sdc2/dev:8:34
/sys/class/block/sdd/dev:8:48
/sys/class/block/sdd1/dev:8:49
/sys/class/block/sdd2/dev:8:50
/sys/class/block/sde/dev:8:64
/sys/class/block/sdf/dev:8:80
/sys/class/block/sdg/dev:8:96
/sys/class/block/sdh/dev:8:112
/sys/class/block/sdi/dev:8:128
/sys/class/block/sr0/dev:11:0
/sys/class/block/sr1/dev:11:1
/sys/class/block/sr2/dev:11:2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My path was slightly different, including here for reference: `grep ^ /sys/block/*/dev`

Comment: Note that this solution cover flush processes corresponding to devices that don't have a file in `/dev/` like NFS mounts. You can get view these numbering of these types of devices with Dyslexic's solution though.

Answer (score 8):

You should also be able to figure this out by searching for those numbers in /proc/self/mountinfo, eg:

```
$ grep 8:32 /proc/self/mountinfo
25 22 8:32 / /var rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/mapper/sysvg-var rw,barrier=1,data=ordered
```

This has the side benefit of working with nfs as well:

```
$ grep 0:73 /proc/self/mountinfo
108 42 0:73 /foo /mnt/foo rw,relatime - nfs host.domain.com:/volume/path rw, ...
```

Note, the data I included here is fabricated, but the mechanism works just fine.